# How to pass Places API autocomplete widget to a custom dialog?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

How can I pass my autocomplete widget fragment inside a custom dialog? As of this moment I have successfully passed my autocomplete fragment inside my fragment, my problem now is how do I pass that fragment inside a custom dialog? Every time I try to put

```
   // Initialize the AutocompleteSupportFragment.
   AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment)                
     getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);

   autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME));
   autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {

   @Override
   public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
   // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
   Log.i("PLACESAPI", "Place: " + place.getName() + ", " + place.getId());
   }
   @Override
   public void onError(Status status) {
   // TODO: Handle the error.
   Log.i("PLACESAPI", "An error occurred: " + status);
   }
   });
```

inside my dialog, errors pop up saying that I can't use getChildFragmentManager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed my problem, I used a DalogFragment and passed the widget to my dialogfragment xml layout file and the code inside my DialogFragment. I hope this can help anyone.